# Science fiction book from the 70's(?) about viruses

Tags: story-identification, books, virus

In high school in the 70's, we read a science fiction book that, in many of the opening chapters, the characters recounted a history of things, referred to only by unintelligible strings of letters and numbers, that were killing people. A fair way into the book it is revealed that these things were influenza viruses.

At the time, I thought it was kind of far fetched, but now I'd say it was prophetic!

Comment: Is this science fictional or fantastical in anyway? Was it somehow set in the far future?

Comment: I'm not sure; I am posting this question for a friend who asked about the book. He referred to it as science fiction.

Comment: You might have to ask your friend for more details, you should anyway cos this is quite brief. However, it is currently very borderline as to whether it is on topic or not.

Comment: I've asked.  Hopefully he can remember more details.